# Flutter / Firebase Scheduled notification with Firebase cloud function

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am developing mobile application with Flutter / Firebase.

So the situation is ,

Admin user create the form. When the admin user create the form ,I would like to add
a scheduled function.

so the Function is like , reminding function, which will be executed like next three days , once a day.

this function will check first will check the document of the form, If the form is opened, next It will check the list of the people who didn't submit.

With that list I would like to send notification for them as I scheduled.

So the questions is

How can I run the scheduled cloud function ?

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
  return null;
});
```

this Function will not work for me , cause which is calling the function every 5 minutes, I want to call the functions in specific times that I want.

```
    exports.formSubmitReminder = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
       // call the scheduled function
        //functiosn is  like
        (data)=>{//scheduled function
            var form =   // get the form from the data;
            if(form.isOpened){// check if the form is opened
                //get the unsubmited user list  from form
                unsubmitedUserList.forEach(async (userId) => {
                    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(ownerId, {
                        notification: {
                            title: `${userModel.data().name}`,
                            body: `Please submit your form`,
                            clickAction: notificationClickAction,
                            sound: 'default',
                        }
                    });
                });
                
    
            } 
    
    
        }
```

Something like this.

Thanks for reading. I am waiting for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You asked how to schedule a Cloud Function in such a way that it executes the next 3 days, once a day.

You should use the approach described in this article: [How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks (to build a Firestore document TTL).](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a)

This approach is based on Cloud Tasks and on two Cloud Functions:

- The first Cloud Function is to be triggered when the admin user create the form (maybe via a Firestore triggered Cloud Function or a Callable Cloud Function, you don't give any detail) and it will schedule 3 Cloud Tasks to be executed during the next 3 days;
- The second Cloud Function, of type HTTPS, will be invoked 3 times by Cloud Tasks, according to the configuration you made in the first Cloud Function. And it is this Cloud Function which will implement the business logic you shared in your question (i.e. checks the document of the form, checks the list of the people who didn't submit, sends notifications, etc..)

---

Note that:

- If you need to share data between the three executions you can save and read data in a Firestore document for example.
- You cloud very well call three different Cloud Functions, one for each day. Just indicate a different HTTPS Cloud Function for each Cloud Tasks configuration.
- You won’t be able to schedule a task to execute greater than 30 days in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I have learned many things.

Comment: @DaegilPyo Glad I could help you. If my answer solved your problem, please accept it in such a way other users know it is one correct solution.